# Is this a proper usage of Function interface?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am trying to get familiar with lambda functions. To start with I decided to write a handy class called `TernaryOperator`. So, the question is did I get the ideology right or am I missing something as it should be done in a different way?

```
public class TernaryOperator<T, U> implements Function<T, U> {

    private final Function<T, U> f;

    public TernaryOperator(Predicate<? super T> condition,
                           Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifTrue,
                           Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifFalse) {
        this.f = t -> condition.test(t) ? ifTrue.apply(t) : ifFalse.apply(t);
    }

    @Override
    public U apply(T t) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }
}
```

I see usage of this class like this:

```
Predicate<Object> condition = Objects::isNull;
Function<Object, Integer> ifTrue = obj -> 0;
Function<CharSequence, Integer> ifFalse = CharSequence::length;
Function<String, Integer> safeStringLength = new TernaryOperator<>(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse);
```

And now I can calculate a length of any string even if it is a null with this oneliner.

So, if you have any ideas how to write better `TernaryOperator` or if you think that it is useless, please tell me.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine.

Comment: This is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to implement the `Function` interface. It's better to write static method in some appropriate class instead:

```
public static <T, U> Function<T, U> ternary(Predicate<? super T> condition,
                       Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifTrue,
                       Function<? super T, ? extends U> ifFalse) {
    return t -> condition.test(t) ? ifTrue.apply(t) : ifFalse.apply(t);
}
```

And use like this:

```
Function<String, Integer> safeStringLength = MyClass.ternary(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse);
```

Also consider using `import static` for your utility class and write simply `ternary(condition, ifTrue, ifFalse)`.

Probably such method could be useful in some situations. Especially when you can use method references. For example:

```
Stream.of(strings).map(ternary(String::isEmpty, x -> "none", String::trim))...
```

Comment: But ask yourself whether `ternary(String::isEmpty, x -> "none", String::trim)` is really better than the expression `s -> s.isEmpty()? "none": s.trim()`…